# Colorama not working as expected while using init and Fore

Tags: python, colorama

I had installed the colorama libary and was writing it in python 3.12 . Then, I tried to use colorama but it didn't work as expected.

First of course, I imported init and Fore. Then I typed init().After that I wroted print(Fore.RED +"some red text"). It gave this random string of words and letters.
[[31msome red text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfwnF.png)
After reading some posts, I used init(convert=True). Still, the color did not change. I would like to find a way to bypass this bug quickly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using IDLE?

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3.12 IDLE